# Android - Pause MediaPlayer when using the microphone?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How can I pause `MediaPlayer` streaming when I use microphone on other apps? E.g. Whatsapp or Telegram?

Comment: Try searching for AUDIO_FOCUS

Comment: Already searched for it, but seems that using the microphone doesn't trigger AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in this way:

```
var audoRecordingCallback = @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
object : AudioRecordingCallback() {
    override fun onRecordingConfigChanged(configs: List<AudioRecordingConfiguration>) {
        super.onRecordingConfigChanged(configs)
        println(configs)
        val isMicOn = try {
            configs.isNotEmpty()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }

        if (isMicOn) {
            pauseAudioWithoutFocus()
        } else {
            playAudioWithoutFocus()
        }
    }
}

fun registerMicrophoneListener() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        this.audioManager.registerAudioRecordingCallback(audoRecordingCallback, null)
    }
}

fun unregisterMicrophoneListener() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        this.audioManager.unregisterAudioRecordingCallback(audoRecordingCallback)
    }
}
```

And calling registerAudioRecordingCallback and unregisterMicrophoneListener whenever you want